# Running single test function in Nose NOT associated with unittest subclass

Tags: python, nose

`nose` discovers tests beginning with `test_`, as well as subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`.

If one wishes to run a single `TestCase` test, e.g.:

```
# file tests.py
class T(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something():
        1/0
```

This can be done on the command line with:

```
nosetests tests:T.test_something
```

I sometimes prefer to write a simple function and skip all the `unittest` boilerplate:

```
def test_something_else():
    assert False
```

In that case, the test will still be run by `nose` when it runs all my tests.  But how can I tell `nose` to run only that test, using the (Unix) command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be:

```
nosetests tests:test_something_else
```

An additional tip is to use attributes

```
from nose.plugins.attrib import attr

@attr('now')
def test_something_else():
    pass
```

To run all tests tagged with the attribute, execute:

```
nosetests -a now
```

Inversely, avoid running those tests:

```
nosetests -a !now
```

Comment: Perfect!  Not sure why I didn't stumble across that while I was poking around.  Thanks!